# Using Google Earth Engine Python Api for NDVI range wise area Calculation?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am using Google Earth Engine Python Api for calculating the area of crop fields and to identify good, avg or bad areas of the cropping areas. For this, I am using the below codes

```
ndvi = clip.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])

bad=ndvi.gte(-0.99)and(ndvi.lte(0.4)).rename('bad')

avg=ndvi.gt(0.4) and(ndvi.lte(0.7)).rename('avg')

good=ndvi.gt(0.7)and(ndvi.lte(1)).rename('good')

clip = clip.addBands(ndvi).addBands(avg).addBands(bad).addBands(good)

areas = clip.select(['avg', 'bad', 'good']).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.sum$

    bad_area = areas.getInfo()['bad']*0.0001

avg_area = areas.getInfo()['avg']*0.0001

good_area = areas.getInfo()['good']*0.0001

print(areas.getInfo())    
print(bad_area)    
print(avg_area)    
print(good_area)
```

But the function is returning all the time the same exact/almost same valus of good amount with the bad and avg amount.

```
{u'bad': 8993438.423736611, u'avg': 8993438.423736611, u'good': 8993438.423736611}
899.343842374
899.343842374
899.343842374
```

I am not able to understand what wrong I am done in the code.

[image: Printed Result of the above code]

I have checked for different areas too and it is confirmed that good, avg and bad values are not just co-incidence